# given we have $p$ votes for $A$ and $q$ votes for $B$, what is the probability that after $k$ of the votes counted ,$A$ will be ahead?

Tags: probability

I was inspired by Bertrand's ballot problem I discovered today thanks to a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853170/probability-quant-suggestions#comment3792770_1853170) in this site.
My question is basically this: given we have $p$ votes for $A$ and $q$ votes for $B$, what is the probability that after $k$ of the votes counted, $A$ will be ahead ?

Example: $p=100$ $q=80$. Q: what is the chance $A$ will have more votes than $B$ after 36 (20%) counted votes ?

When I think of it, I have even some problem calculating the probability of an *exact* result: for example, what is the chance for 20-16 after 36 votes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like taking out $k$ votes out of an urn that contains $p$ votes for $A$ and $q$ votes for $B$ and we are dealing with [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

An expression for the probability that $A$ will be ahead is:$$\binom{p+q}{k}^{-1}\sum_{i>\frac12k}\binom{p}{i}\binom{q}{k-i}$$

I have no closed expression for this summation.

If $p=100$ and $q=80$ then the chance for $20-16$ after counting $36$ votes is:$$\frac{\binom{100}{20}\binom{80}{16}}{\binom{180}{36}}$$